# firebase error 403 Permission denied to get service [runtimeconfig.googleapis.com] stripe key

Tags: firebase, api, stripe-payments, native

I was trying to implement on a Native react project my stripe key using the command

```
firebase functions:config:set stripe.key=<your key>
```

But unfortunately I caught this error message on my console:
`Error: HTTP Error: 403, Permission denied to get service [runtimeconfig.googleapis.com]`
The closest solution I find around says that I need to change my rules on the cloud firestore for something like this...

```
{
"rules": {
".read": "true",
".write": "true"
 }
}
```

I find this code outdated and also not useful for my issue. Please let me know the steps to solve this issue. Thanks for reading!